# Macro that will add number entered into fax address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I have a faxfinder fax appliance that we use to send faxes. This can be done through outlook by formatting the addres as so, FAX=FaxNumber@faxfinder.domain.local. I've created the below macro that will pop up a box and ask for the fax number and then puts that number in the To field of an email.

Is there a way for me to append the rest of the address to whatever number is entered? I want to make it easy for the users so they don't have to remember the rest of the address.

```
Public Sub CreateNewMessage()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

FaxTo = InputBox("Please enter fax number")
 With objMsg
  .To = FaxTo


  .Display
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can change the variable of FaxTo and append text before and after.

In your case, part of your code would become as follows (I only copy the 2 lines of code that the rest goes in between)

```
FaxTo = InputBox("Please enter fax number")
'new code here
FaxTo = "FAX=" & FaxTo & "@faxfinder.domain.local"
'end of new code
 With objMsg
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you for the help.